# Changing position during animation?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, animation

I have an UIImageView with the size of `64x64`. I want to animate its size down to 8x8. It works fine. However when i change position of point1 (touchPositionInView) from outside the animation it won't update and it will instead animate from the original position where the touches began. Is there any way to fix this?

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"widen" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    CGRect newRect = yellow.frame;
    newRect.size.height = 8;
    newRect.size.width = 8;
    yellow.center = point1;
    yellow.frame = newRect;
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    point1 = [touch locationInView:View];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that `touchesBegan:withEvent:` is only called once and `touchesMoved:withEvent:` is called on every movement.

I suggest you add an animation block in your `touchesMoved:withEvent:` method also. :-)

**Store the point1 and resize your  image to 8, 8 and start position animation.**

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    point1 = [touch locationInView:View];

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"widen" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    CGRect newRect = yellow.frame;
    newRect.size = CGSizeMake(8, 8);
    yellow.frame = newRect;
    [self updatePoint:NO];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

**Update the position on every move and start the position animation.**

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    point1 = [touch locationInView:View];
    [self updatePoint:YES];
}
```

**Do the position animation.**

```
- (void)updatePoint:(BOOL)animated
{

    // I think it would be an approvement, if you calculate the duration by the distance from the
    // current point to the target point
    if (animated)
    {
        yellow.center = point1;
    }
    else
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                              delay:0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent
                         animations:^{
                             yellow.center = point1;
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){}
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: When i move the the touch it will first change the size to 8,8 THEN it will move to the position. I want it to change size and position at at the same time :)

Comment: I updated the answer, so it now should correctly animate both. Give it a try. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the `UIView`'s **`animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`** method and provide `UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState` and `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` in options.

Source:

[UIView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewAnimationOptions)